# How can I draw a black shadow in webkit browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webkit

How can I draw a BLACK shadow in webkit browsers with the HTML5 canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem! Webkit does not how to process shadow when blur is not set or set to zero. In this case it shows shadow in the same color as the text. Firefox shows it correctly in both case (blur not set or blur equal zero).

Answer (score 0):

On Canvas?

It should be the same as any other browser:

```
ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
```

See an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpvFF/4/

Tested on Safari 5 and Chrome 12

Comment: Whats wrong with it? I see an elaborate object with a gradient, but the object has a black shadow...

Comment: Well I'm trying to make it work for android, but for me in chrome it is also displayed incorrect. The shadow is the same color as the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

`shadowColor = "rgb(255,100,100)";`

See an example [here](http://falcon80.com/HTMLCanvas/ImageManipulation/AddShadow.html).